# Home HVAC condenser fan not spinning

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

The Bryant condenser outside the house was making a noise like it wants the fan to spin but the fan wasn't spinning. I pushed the fan with a stick and it started spinning, but reluctantly, like 4 revolutions per second.

What is this symptomatic of? What is the potential solution? Can a DIYer do it?

My research shows that I have a "bad fan motor and/or bad start capacitor". Does that sound right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor is the most likely culprit . They are easy to change out (with the power off). They are usually silver cans with several connections on 1 end. You need to find the size it will be something like 15mfd then the voltage. It may be a dual element then there will be 2 numbers like 15 - 28 mfd.
Make sure to write down the terminals the diferent wires go to so you get them correct on the new one. The caps can be found on line for the best price.

Comment: Will try it out tonight.

Comment: Indeed, it was the blown start-run capacitor. A ten minute repair. I wonder how much an HVAC company would've charged.